# USB device not being mounted on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb, mount

We are trying to mount a cellphone Razr I through USB on a Windows 8 platform.

It was working before, but now, the device doesn't show up at all on this Windows laptop and neither on a Mac.

I had a problem similar to this once with an external hard drive, and the solution was something like:

- Access a hidden directory which contained a reference to this volume that wasn't unmounted properly.
- Force unmount the device from there. And then just plugging the usb cable in would mount the device fine.

But I don't remember which directory was that. Does anyone know how to fix this, or where is the directory with the broken volumes?

Comment: On Windows does it show up in Device Manager and Disk Management? I suppose you tried a different cable.